# mysql - Query with IFNULL and CONCAT_WS returns empty string instead predefined IFNULL parameter in case of NULL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, subquery, ifnull, concat-ws

I am working on the complex MySQL query with subquery and `JOIN`s and this is my query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    ancient_source_name,
    ancient_source_name_alt,
    ancient_source_type,
    ancient_source_type_id,
    IFNULL(IF(ancient_source_material = 'Unknown', NULL, ancient_source_material), '-') AS ancient_source_material,
    ancient_source_year,
    dynasty,
    ancient_period,
    author,
    IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(', ',
        IF(provenance_country = 'Unknown' OR provenance_country = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_country),
        IF(provenance_locality = 'Unknown' OR provenance_locality = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_locality),
        IF(provenance_place = 'Unknown' OR provenance_place = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_place)
    ), '-') AS provenance_loc,
    IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(', ',
        IF(current_country = 'Unknown' OR current_country = 'Not Applicable', NULL, current_country),
        IF(current_locality = 'Unknown' OR current_locality = 'Not Applicable', NULL, current_locality),
        IF(current_place = 'Unknown' OR current_place = 'Not Applicable', NULL, current_place)
    ), '-') AS current_loc
FROM (
    SELECT
        hgn_ancient_sources.id AS id,
        ancient_source_name,
        IFNULL(ancient_source_name_alt, '-') AS ancient_source_name_alt,
        IFNULL(ancient_source_year, '-') AS ancient_source_year,
        ancient_source_type,
        ancient_source_type_id,
        ancient_source_material,
        dynasty,
        ancient_period,
        provenance_countries.country AS provenance_country,
        provenance_localities.locality AS provenance_locality,
        provenance_places.place AS provenance_place,
        current_countries.country AS current_country,
        current_localities.locality AS current_locality,
        current_places.place AS current_place,
        IFNULL(author_name, '-') AS author
    FROM hgn_ancient_sources
    JOIN hgn_ancient_source_types ON hgn_ancient_sources.ancient_source_type_id = hgn_ancient_source_types.id
    JOIN hgn_ancient_source_materials ON hgn_ancient_sources.ancient_source_material_id = hgn_ancient_source_materials.id
    JOIN hgn_dynasties ON hgn_ancient_sources.ancient_source_dynasty_id = hgn_dynasties.id
    JOIN hgn_ancient_periods ON hgn_ancient_sources.ancient_source_period_id = hgn_ancient_periods.id
    LEFT JOIN junc_ancient_source_has_author ON hgn_ancient_sources.id = junc_ancient_source_has_author.ancient_source_id
    LEFT JOIN hgn_authors ON junc_ancient_source_has_author.author_id = hgn_authors.id
    JOIN junc_place_has_location AS provenance_place_has_location ON hgn_ancient_sources.ancient_source_provenance_place_id = provenance_place_has_location.id
    JOIN junc_place_has_location AS current_place_has_location ON hgn_ancient_sources.ancient_source_current_place_id = current_place_has_location.id
    JOIN junc_locality_has_country AS provenance_locality_has_country ON provenance_place_has_location.location_id = provenance_locality_has_country.id
    JOIN junc_locality_has_country AS current_locality_has_country ON current_place_has_location.location_id = current_locality_has_country.id
    JOIN hgn_places AS provenance_places ON provenance_place_has_location.place_id = provenance_places.id
    JOIN hgn_places AS current_places ON current_place_has_location.place_id = current_places.id
    JOIN hgn_localities AS provenance_localities ON provenance_locality_has_country.locality_id = provenance_localities.id
    JOIN hgn_localities AS current_localities ON current_locality_has_country.locality_id = current_localities.id
    JOIN hgn_countries AS provenance_countries ON provenance_locality_has_country.country_id = provenance_countries.id
    JOIN hgn_countries AS current_countries ON current_locality_has_country.country_id = current_countries.id
) AS subquery
```

Everything works fine except this part of code:

```
IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(', ',
    IF(provenance_country = 'Unknown' OR provenance_country = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_country),
    IF(provenance_locality = 'Unknown' OR provenance_locality = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_locality),
    IF(provenance_place = 'Unknown' OR provenance_place = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_place)
), '-') AS provenance_loc,
IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(', ',
    IF(current_country = 'Unknown' OR current_country = 'Not Applicable', NULL, current_country),
    IF(current_locality = 'Unknown' OR current_locality = 'Not Applicable', NULL, current_locality),
    IF(current_place = 'Unknown' OR current_place = 'Not Applicable', NULL, current_place)
), '-') AS current_loc
```

I am getting good results when there are 1/3 or 2/3 columns with `Unknown` or `Not Applicable` value, but when 3/3 columns (e.g. `current_country`, `current_locality`, `current_place`) has one of these two values, I get empty cell as a result, and not `-`, as should be expected.

I tried different changes in the code, and nothing works. I should mention that, for example, this part of the query:

```
IFNULL(IF(ancient_source_material = 'Unknown', NULL, ancient_source_material), '-') AS ancient_source_material
```

work perfectly, so my assumption is that there is some problem with `CONCAT_WS()` function, but I cannot find what.

Comment: Check this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19805 It is old and its status is "Not a Bug"

Comment: I didn't understand the problem, and what is more important, the solution. Should I use PHP to solve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT_WS()` returns an empty string if all arguments after a non-null separator are `NULL`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=babe155cd376fa05496d38d801154dc0).

I did not find this stated explicitly in [MySql's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) (like it is made clear in [SQL Server's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

What you can do is use also [`NULLIF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif) to check if the result is an empty string and change it to `NULL` before you use `IFNULL()`:

```
  IFNULL(NULLIF(CONCAT_WS(', ',
      IF(provenance_country = 'Unknown' OR provenance_country = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_country),
      IF(provenance_locality = 'Unknown' OR provenance_locality = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_locality),
      IF(provenance_place = 'Unknown' OR provenance_place = 'Not Applicable', NULL, provenance_place)
  ), ''), '-') AS provenance_loc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e43197d8a0e62fe65303daa2f980d623).

Comment: Thank you very much! This elegant solution solved my problem.